# Paragraph Styles in a CSS Style Sheet

Tags: css, xhtml, stylesheet

i am trying to make two different styles for two paragraphs in an xhtml document using a css style sheet. ive tried everything and searched everywhere but nothing has given me a straightforward answer.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: *What* have you tried?

Comment: Could you describe how you're partitioning the paragraphs into 2 groups?

Comment: ive tried different w3 tutorials and FaQ's, as well as html.net tutorials and other programming webistes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

style.css:

```
p.style1 {
    ...
}

p.style2 {
    ...
}
```

page.html:

```
<p class="style1">Paragraph with style1</p>
<p class="style2">Paragraph with style2</p>
```

Straightforward enough? :)

Comment: thankyou so much :) its just stuff like that im trying to figure out. ive only been web programming for a week now; im brand new to coding. that helped massively :D

Comment: you're welcome :) but remember that technically speaking HTML isn't a programming language, but rather a markup language.. so you don't "program in html", at least you write or code HTML!